# IdentityServer4 PostLogoutRedirectUri comes with http

Tags: identityserver4, .net-6.0, openid-connect

I had the same problem with the login redirect uri which was comming with HTTP instead of HTTPS, and managed to solve it with the use of the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider event where I switch **http** with **https**.

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                                      {
                                          OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = RedirectToIdentityProvider
                                      };
```

Now I am experiencing the same behavior, the PostLogoutRedirectUri  which is configured on the Client over in IDS has **https://** but the PostLogoutRedirectUri which I am receving in the endsession event has **http://**

I have tried using the OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect but the RedirectUri on the ctx.ProtocolMessage is null. I have tried other options as well, like specifying the SignedOutRedirectUri/SignedOutCallbackPath but nothing works.

*#Edit 1*

I think I managed to grasp something, since the application is sending the request on signout, I should intervene on another **OIDC** event, which is **OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut**. This was promising, but the problem is it only work on localhost for some reason.

The event is taking a RedirectContext which on the Servers is coming in as null. On localhost its fine. Also, it is the same RedirectContext which I am using for the **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** event. I am confused.

#Solution

At some point, the OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut event stopped getting a null context and it all worked out since then. So yeah, use this event if you have to alter the redirect callback URI.